# Send Promise response from Swift - React native Native modules

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I implemented a native module on React Native. When I'm calling a function from RN it will call the Swift module to get the response.

```
const response = await voiceRecognizing();
console.log('Response from Native module', response);
```

Now I have an issue with the Swift module. When I'm sending a Promise response with the below code it's working fine, Since resolve and reject are available as argument. So that I can able to send a response

```
@objc(voiceRecognizing:withRejecter:)
func voiceRecognizing(resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
  let resultsDict = [
      "success" : true
    ];
    resolve([resultsDict])
}
```

But I'm calling some async function inside Swift So that I wanna to use `DispatchQueue.global` So Inside DispatchQueue, When I use `resolve([resultsDict])` it's throwing error.

```
@objc(voiceRecognizing:withRejecter:)
func voiceRecognizing(resolve:RCTPromiseResolveBlock,reject:RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
 
     DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
          let result = self.recognizeFromMic()
 let resultsDict = [
      "result" : result
    ];
          resolve([resultsDict])
      }
}
```

I'm not that much familiar with developing native modules in Swift.  Any suggestions on how to overcome this issue? Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you add some details - are you working on Turbo Module or this is an old architecture?